# Multiple values with Radio Button in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below property in my model

```
public bool? Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I want to create a Radio button which gives three option Yes No and N/A which I do using this

```
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Data, true)Yes<br />
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Data, false)No<br/>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Data, false)N/A
```

The issue is that it is always making N/A selected even if choose No. Is there a way I can use the bool type in the model and make these three options work.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6787687/40822

Comment: You have two radio buttons with the value `false`. Change the value to an empty string as it is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783961/mvc-bind-post-boolean-to-radiobutton).

Comment: Works good. Thanks guys.